# PostgreSQL asynchronous cluster with partial synchronous commits

Tags: postgresql, cluster

We`re planning a complete synchronous PG Cluster with 3 nodes but we asked ourselves if its possible to have an asynchronous cluster with partial synchronous commits.

Normally you make your cluster completly synchronous and you can tell single transactions to be asynchronous by setting "SET LOCAL synchronous_commit TO OFF". Is there the other way also or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it the other way around.

Just set it up like a normal synchronous cluster, but set `synchronous_commit = off` in `postgresql.conf`. Then:

```
SET LOCAL synchronous_commit TO ON
```

in transactions you want to commit synchronously.

Keep in mind, though, that a synchronous commit will force prior commits to flush before it can commit. So if you do commits `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [sync]6, 7, 8`, then commits 1 through 6 *inclusive* must be flushed before commit 6 can report success.

Comment: Thank you for that answer! But when i set it up like a synchronous cluster and only leave synchronous commit off i still need to define synchronous hot-standbys in the synchronous_application_name parameter thing, so that the master knows which hot-standby he has to take for the synchronous commit. is that right?

Comment: .. what do you recommend? asynch cluster with partial synch commits or a synch cluster with partial asynch (about 80% asynch) commits!? we now have the plan to go the synch cluster way. what du you think?

Comment: Personally I think it's *way* safer to always sync commit, unless you explicitly request async. A `SET` statement is nearly free, and it's a lot better to say "it's OK to be unsafe, I'll take the risk this time" than "please be safe this time". And yes, you're correct, you still need the `synchronous_standby_names`, etc.